# Get shortcode attribute from parent shortcode

Tags: wordpress, inheritance, nested, attributes, shortcode

quick question, that I didn't find anything on the web after intensive searching.

In the inner shortcode of a nested shortcode I would like to get a attributes of the parent shortcode. Is there any solution without a global variable? I found the shortcode_parse_atts() functionality but it seems like that only works the other way around (get attributes in the parent shortcode from the inner nested shortcode).

Any help or hint is appreciated

Comment: No, you can't get the  "parent" shortcode attributes from the "child" shortcode. There is not connection or inheritance between them. Consider them as single functions, so may be cookie or session variables are you best choice (though, I don't know what is you use case, there might be something that you can do with the logic of the nested shortcodes).

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Appreciate the help